# Android: app crashes after going back and pressing a button

Tags: android, media-player

My Android app crashes after a specific set of `Buttons` are pressed. Basically, the `Activity` has two `Buttons`. One plays a sound and the other opens another `Activity`. But after going back with the back button and pressing the sound `Button` again, it will crash the app. I'm not sure why since the `Button` works the first time. I thought I had to reset the `MediaPlayer` but it still crashes.

My `Activity`:

```
public class Tables1 extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mysound;
    protected boolean active = true;
    protected int splashtime = 17000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.twotime1);
        mysound = MediaPlayer.create(Tables1.this, R.raw.two1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mysound.stop();
        mysound.reset();
        mysound.release();
        mysound = null;
    }

    public void listen(View view) {

        mysound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mysound) {
                mysound.release();
            }

        });
        mysound.start();
    }

    public void Next(View view) {
        if (mysound.isPlaying()) {
            mysound.stop();
            mysound.reset();
        } else {
            Log.d("Exercise", "not working ");
        }

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.example", "com.example.twotimes.Exercise1");
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void back(View view) {
        if (mysound.isPlaying()) {
            mysound.stop();
        }

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.example", "com.example.timestableseasy.Menu2");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    ... 11 more
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1082)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    at com.example.twotimes.Tables1.listen(Tables1.java:52)
05-30 15:00:35.954: E/AndroidRuntime(31572):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Which line is line 52 in your `Tables1.listen()` method?

Comment: @indivisible, it's quite obviously `mySound.start()`, based on the logcat and the ubiquitous `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @323go, I know but the OP didn't know to look there or how to read the stacktrace so I thought I'd poke them in the right direction. Maybe I should have been clearer and a little more verbose.

Comment: yes the problem is there but why does it work once then when the user goes back and presses the button a second time (after the sound has played) crashes the app

Comment: @323go its not a duplicate since the problem was why the button didn't work a second time as it worked normal when pressed first. the question has already been answered with an actual answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Android Documentation:

> "IllegalStateException: the internal player engine has not been
>   initialized or has been released."

When you go to your new `Activity` via an `Intent`, your previous `Activity` goes through your `onDestroy()` method:

```
mysound.stop();
mysound.reset();
mysound.release();
```

your `mysound` is not re-created once the user presses the back button.
Try changing your `listen()` method to this:

```
public void listen(View view) {
    mysound = MediaPlayer.create(Tables1.this, R.raw.two1);
    mysound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mysound) {
            mysound.release();
        }

    });
    mysound.start();
}
```

Comment: thanx i actually just found that out. i would also need to put the "mysound = MediaPlayer.create(Tables1.this, R.raw.two1);" in the next method.

Comment: also thank you for answering my question instead of just pointing out where the error is. i knew where it was just wasn't aware that the mysound.release(); gets rid of the object